Optimizing Transmission of Large Objects via SignalR: Minimizing Data Size for 100MB Payload
I want to send a large object, roughly equivalent to 100MB, to a client using SignalR. Are there any ways to minimize its size effectively?
I had tried to Compress the data before sending it to reduce its size and Split the data into smaller chunks and send them sequentially.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
